# How to get all items in a view using REST API

Tags: rest, list-view, custom-list

by using rest api

I get items like this

```
http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/Items
```

I get the view like this and naturally in it I have the GUID

```
http://mydomain/_api/web/lists/GetByTitle('MyList')/views/getbytitle('MyView')
```

Now how can I get all items under this certain view

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using REST you can't get items from a view. For that you have two options

1. Get the view fields and form a query
2. Create a CAML query and use it to get the items.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/sharepoint/en-US/a5815727-925b-4ac5-8a46-b0979a910ebb/query-listitems-by-view-through-rest-api

Answer (score 30):

The following example demonstrates how to retrieve list items for a View using SharePoint REST:

```
function getListItems(webUrl,listTitle, queryText) 
{
    var viewXml = '<View><Query>' + queryText + '</Query></View>';
    var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('" + listTitle + "')/getitems"; 
    var queryPayload = {  
               'query' : {
                      '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.CamlQuery' }, 
                      'ViewXml' : viewXml  
               }
    };
    return executeJson(url,"POST",null,queryPayload);
}


function getListViewItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewTitle)
{
     var url = webUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('" + listTitle + "')/Views/getbytitle('" + viewTitle + "')/ViewQuery";
     return executeJson(url).then(
         function(data){         
             var viewQuery = data.d.ViewQuery;
             return getListItems(webUrl,listTitle,viewQuery); 
         });
}
```

where

```
function executeJson(url,method,headers,payload) 
{
    method = method || 'GET';
    headers = headers || {};
    headers["Accept"] = "application/json;odata=verbose";
    if(method == "POST") {
        headers["X-RequestDigest"] = $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val();
    }      
    var ajaxOptions = 
    {       
       url: url,   
       type: method,  
       contentType: "application/json;odata=verbose",
       headers: headers
    };
    if (typeof payload != 'undefined') {
      ajaxOptions.data = JSON.stringify(payload);
    }  
    return $.ajax(ajaxOptions);
}
```

**Usage**

```
getListViewItems(_spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl,'Tasks','All Tasks')
.done(function(data)
{
     var items = data.d.results;
     for(var i = 0; i < items.length;i++) {
         console.log(items[i].Title);
     }    
})
.fail(
function(error){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
});
```

Comment: Thax Vadim Gremyachev, your code is solid :)

Comment: Really nice code! I'm using it to format some view data with D3. thanks, Stephan Onisick

Comment: @Vadim, but in this you are explicitly writing column name as `items[i].Title`. But is it possible to only get selected fields in that view?

Comment: Hello Vadim, I am getting 403 forbidden error for above code? Is there any solution for that?

Answer (score 1):

I usually use this approach when querying a list:

```
_api/web/lists(guid'D38E6516-FB4F-4FCF-9E29-4FEC9CE06D2B')/GetItems(query=@v1)?@v1={"ViewXml":"<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='Your field here'><Value Type='The field type'>The value you want to look for</Value></Eq></Where></Query><ViewFields><FieldRef Name='Id' /></ViewFields></View>"}
```

The guid being the guid of the list (This saves you some headache if the list name ever changes).

This needs to be called as a POST call, not a GET call (Like your normal browser request).

Also when constructing the CAML part you can help yourself a lot by using a CAML builder like U2U or similar.