# how to get the count of items in a list view using javascript

Tags: list, javascript, view

I have a list WSR, there is view in it called 'Overdue'. I want to get the count of the items in this view using javascript. Please help

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get all items in a view using REST API](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-rest-api)

Comment: If the answer was helpful could you remove it from the SO unanswered list, by marking it as answered, tnx

Answer (score 1):

Using Full Rest API

```
$.ajax({
    url: _spPageContextInfo.webAbsoluteUrl + "/_api/web/lists/getbytitle('your_list')/items?$select=your_field,Title",
    method: "GET",
    headers: { "accept": "application/json;odata=verbose", },
    success: function (data) {
        var cosa = complete(data.d.results, "SubProcesoId")
        console.log(JSON.stringify(cosa));
    },
    error: function (data) {
        console.log(data);
    }
});

function complete(items,propertyName)
{
    var result = [];
    var obj = {};
    $.each(items, function(index, item) {
        var obj = {};
        obj.subp = item.SubProcesoId;
        obj.title = item.Title;
        result.push(obj);
    });
    return result;
}
```

This will return a JSON object with all the elements in the list. Using the [underscorejs library](http://underscorejs.org/), you can group by and get the count per repeted item.

```
console.log( _.groupBy(orders, function(obj){
    return obj["subp"];
}));
```

This is the example of my test
https://jsfiddle.net/hetdapuv/

Answer (score 1):

When you query the Lists.asmx web services, it's result set XML response already contains the row count in an attribute value of the `rs:data` element which is what you need if you target the specific view and don't exceed the query `RowLimit` setting. Otherwise, you'll have to count.

Marc D Anderson's SPServices library now on GitHub has awesome documentation and samples.

Answer (score 1):

If the View is **displayed**

Add a Content Editor WebPart **below** the View on the page

and execute:

```
console.log('There are', ctx.ListData.Row.length,' items in this View (page)');
```