# Create list datasheet view using the REST api

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-rest-api, view, json, datasheet

Provided following body content for a SharePoint REST api call:

```
{
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.View' },
  'Title': 'Awesome View',
  'PersonalView': false
}
```

This creates a new view named `Amesome View` for the list on which the api call is executed. The type of this view will be a default view.

My question is: is there a way to create a **datasheet** view using the REST api?

I have found nothing on this and I searched for the SharePoint Client [**ViewType**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.client.view.viewtype.aspx) property on *MSDN*, and it shows that this is a `get` property, no `set` available.

So, using *CSOM* it won't be possible at all I assume. I've also tried providing the `ViewType` property, just to be sure:

```
{
  '__metadata': { 'type': 'SP.View' },
  'Title': 'Awesome View',
  'PersonalView': false,
  "ViewType": "GRID"
}
```

The `GRID` value comes from the [**ViewType enumeration**](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewtype.aspx). (Also tried using the in value or lower-case). But all this didn't work.

So, is there a way to achieve this through the REST api?

**Edit:**

To clarify: sadly, *CSOM* or *PowerShell* are not an option.

Comment: Check this Link : [Sharepoint view list item](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/a/136002/8068)

Comment: @Alivarzeshi Did you read the question properly? I want to **create** a view, not get items from a specific view.

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand if you are able to use CSOM or must use REST. But when reading on msdn there is a class namned [ViewCreationInformation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-se/library/office/microsoft.sharepoint.client.viewcreationinformation_members.aspx) which has a ViewTypeKind Property which is get/set.

But no it does not seem to be a way to do this when using the REST api.

Here is an example using PowerShell

```
$list = Get-PnPList -Identity "testlist" #Im using PnP to get the list.

$vci = New-Object Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewCreationInformation
$vci.Title = "My Awsome View"
$vci.PersonalView = $true
$vci.ViewTypeKind = [Microsoft.SharePoint.Client.ViewType]::Grid

#Add some fields to show in view
$vci.ViewFields = [string[]]@("Title","flightnr")

$view = $list.Views.Add($vci)

$list.Update()

$list.Context.ExecuteQuery()
```

Which results in the following view:

[image: My awsome view]

Comment: Thanks for your answerr. In my situation it has to be REST, no other option (updated my question). Would the `ViewTypeKind` property available/working in REST?

Comment: @Abbas no i don't think so. What I can see there is no way of setting ViewTypeKind using the REST api.

Answer (score 0):

Search this : Create a view in this link
[POST request example: Create a view](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn531433.aspx#bk_ViewFieldCollection)

> When you create a view, the server returns the view. To add, remove,
>   or change the order of view fields for the new view, use the
>   **ViewFieldCollection methods**.