# How to get specific listview data with javascript?

Tags: list, javascript, list-view, jsom

I got a list and a list view. But I want to retrieve only particular list view's data.

How can i do that with javascript ?

Comment: Duplicate? https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/q/135936/8992

Comment: Not a duplicate.  He’s asking for view data, not just the view properties

Answer (score 0):

There's a lot of advantages to doing this.  The trick is to get the caml query off of the list view before querying the list for items.

```
var ctx = new SP.ClientContext.get_current(),
    list = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(<list title>),
    views = list.get_views(),
    view = views.getByTitle(<view name>),
    items;

ctx.load(views);
ctx.executeQueryAsync(
    function(){
        var camlQuery = new SP.CamlQuery();
        camlQuery.set_viewXml(view.get_listViewXml());
        items = list.getItems(camlQuery);
        ctx.load(items);
        ctx.executeQueryAsync(
            function(){
                //items variable will be populated with items from view
            },
            function(sender, args){
                console.error('List items could not be retrieved');
            }
        );
    },
    function(){}
);
```

The down side is that there's 2 execute's in order to make this work.  one in order to get the data from the list view, the 2nd one to pass in the query pulled from the specific view.

I have a few gists that I use this on for utility sake.
[Delete List View Items](https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/1b2e7f989eb6ac58f365f4a7b3f6a8e1)

[Recycle List View Items](https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/35a54ae726a2615548b0cfbb3c9ceeb3)

[Touch List View Items](https://gist.github.com/BigRaj/3717b130273bb94021905c6875195696) - Used to Trigger on change workflows for all items in a specific view.

You should be able to pull out the general logic or modify for your own extension method on SP.List