# Creating a pretty table from a SharePoint list

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, sharepoint-list

I have a small list (7 items and 8 columns) which I Want to display on another public facing page.
Ideally I want the end result to look similar to this table[image: this]

Nothing needs to be added or editable by the viewer. End game is to amend the list in the background which in turn will update this much prettier, front facing table.

Comment: nice screenshot, but it doesn't tell us anything about the data structure. If you cannot build it with a SharePoint built-in list web part, you may need to build a custom web part, which involves coding with the SharePoint Framework.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new client-side webpart using CEWP that will get your list items via a REST call. Then you can simply render the result in an HTML table. You can style an HTML table however you want using CSS.

**Examples**

- [Getting list items via REST](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/135936/how-to-get-all-items-in-a-view-using-rest-api)
- [Who Needs a Data View Web Part? SharePoint REST and DataTables](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=f4S3qo3kWz8) Very old video, but might still be an option for you.

If you have SharePoint 2016,  2019 or SPO, you can create an SPFx webpart that does the same.

Comment: Thank you. Looking into this, I managed to make it so when a button is pressed it does pull the table data through. Great.

But there are two issue, one, can I set this to load the table without a button being pressed? I want it to be on a page when the page loads.

Second, I want to style the table, larger font, background colours etc, but unsure how to change the code to reflect this. [Code](https://pastebin.com/JTdztwDg)